# How to use "with"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> "I can't imagine a better monument to your mother," Miss Hurd said with an uncharacteristic catch in her voice.

Why does the word here use "catch" rather than "catching"?
I think that the word put behind "with" should be Ving ?

Answer (score 1):

The word 'catch' in the phrase 'a catch in the voice' is a noun.

> a catch in your voice/throat
>
> From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English
>   a short pause that you make when
>   you are speaking, because you feel upset or are beginning to cry
>
> There was a catch in Anne’s voice and she seemed close to tears.

[A catch in your voice](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-catch-in-your-voice-throat)